# Terraform - if statement to pick appropriate variable

Tags: terraform, oracle-call-interface

Using Terraform to deploy to OCI, I'm wanting to pass in a variable named "nonprod" either true or false to select which compartment I use which is defined in another variable "compartment_ocid".  So based on whether variable "nonprod" is true or false I'm wanting to use a different value in "compartment_ocid".  From my reading, it seems like this would work if they were resources but not variables as it errors for declaring twice.  Any idea how to do this or perhaps a cleaner way of achieving the same thing?

```
variable "nonprod" {
  description = "If set to true, non-prod.  If false, prod"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "compartment_ocid" {
  count = var.nonprod ? 1 : 0
  # Non-Prod compartment
  default = "nonprod_ocid_456"
}

variable "compartment_ocid" {
  count = var.nonprod ? 0 : 1
  # Prod compartment
  default = "prod_ocid_123"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to combine values into a `local` defined by the results of an inline `if`. For example

```
locals {
  compartment_ocid = var.nonprod ? "nonprod_ocid_456" : "prod_ocid_123" 
}
```

Then later you could reference the value as `local.compartment_ocid`.

For more information, see [terraform's documentation on locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html).